# Creating multiple functions with for loop

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

First, I did find a couple links that appeared to address this problem, but my understanding of javascript (and code in general) is pretty bad, and the solutions/explanations were difficult for me to generalize here. I know it has to do with a closure (which I vaguely understand).

**Background:** 
I created 10 checkboxes using a loop, each with 4 radio buttons that are supposed to appear when the checkbox is checked. I can accomplish the "appear/disappear" by creating 10+ functions one-by-one, but I would prefer to create my ten functions with a loop. The code below shows how each checkbox is calling a variable function on change (e.g., t0Disp()).

```
<?
for ($row = 0; $row <10; $row++)
{
  $topic = $topic[$row];
  ?>
  <input id="C<? echo $row ?>" type="checkbox" value="true" onchange="t<? echo $row ?>Disp()" /><? echo $topic ?>
  <br />
  <div id="<? echo $row ?>div" style="display: none">
      <? for ($col = 0; $col < 4; $col++) 
    {
      ?>
      <input type="radio" name="r<? echo $row ?>" value="<? echo $col ?>" onchange="disable<? echo $col ?>(); disable<? echo $row ?>();" />
      <? echo $col+1; ?>
    <?
    }
    ?>
      <br />
      <br />
  </div>
<?
}
?>
```

The code above works fine if I manually input my t0Disp() through t9Disp() functions. When I tried making a for-loop to create these functions (below), the function only works for t9Disp()

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var idiv = i + "div";
    var eldiv = document.getElementById(idiv);
    var ci = "C" + i;
    var elci = document.getElementById(ci);
    window['t' + i + 'Disp'] = function() {
        if(elci.checked == true) {
            eldiv.style.display = "inherit";
        }
        else {
            eldiv.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

I just need to understand why the javascript loop doesn't just spit out 10 distinct functions in the way that my php loop spits out 10 distinct checkboxes?

Thank you!

Comment: You do not need multiple functions.. never in loop..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: In addition to the duplicate, I don't even know why you want 10 functions, instead of simply 1 that takes a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need multiple function, just one function with argument can do it for you!

```js
function disp(elci, eldiv) {
  eldiv = document.getElementById('eldiv');
  if (elci.checked == true) {
    eldiv.style.display = "inherit";
  } else {
    eldiv.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

And your markup will be:

```
<input id="C<? echo $row ?>" type="checkbox" value="true" onchange="Disp(this,'<? echo $row ?>div')" /><? echo $topic ?>
```

Comment: This is so smart! I don't know why I wasn't thinking this way, as it is way more in line with what I'm capable of coding... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `var` is hoisted, so you *do* get ten distinct functions, each one pointing at one **shared** variable ... which points at the last set of checkboxes.

The *first* solution to your problem is to use `let` or `const` (if you only need to support modern browsers):

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    const idiv = i + "div";
    const eldiv = document.getElementById(idiv);
    const ci = "C" + i;
    const elci = document.getElementById(ci);
    window['t' + i + 'Disp'] = function() {
        if(elci.checked == true) {
            eldiv.style.display = "inherit";
        }
        else {
            eldiv.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

However, there is even more you can do:

```
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.js-showChoices');
[].slice.apply(checkboxes).forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', event => {
    if (event.target.checked) getDivFor(event.target).style.display = 'inherit';
    else getDivFor(event.target).style.display = 'none';
  });
});

function getDivFor(checkbox) {
  // Find div based on checkbox and return it
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great! The second box of code is way beyond me, but it certainly looks more elegant than what I've been doing. I think I'm going to stick with Rayon's solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that when functions get added those remember last values of variable `eldi`, `elci`.

You can make use of closure to remember appropriate values of variables.
For that do something like this

```
function addFunction(name, elementDiv, elementCi) {
  window[name] = function() {
    if(elementCi.checked == true) {
        elementDiv.style.display = "inherit";
    }
    else {
        elementDiv.style.display = "none";
    }
 }

}

for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
   var idiv = i + "div";
   var eldiv = document.getElementById(idiv);
   var ci = "C" + i;
   var elci = document.getElementById(ci);
   addFunction('t' + i + 'Disp', eldiv, elci);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sean has the problem right though there would be an easier way to do it than consts and would support previous browsers

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    window['t' + i + 'Disp'] = (function() {
        var idiv = i + "div";
        var eldiv = document.getElementById(idiv);
        var ci = "C" + i;
        var elci = document.getElementById(ci);

        return function() {
            if(elci.checked == true) {
                eldiv.style.display = "inherit";
            } else {
                eldiv.style.display = "none";
            }
        };
    })();
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qxwzLh3g/)

This works by storing the variables in scope inside the first function that's only accessible by the returned function.

Rayon has a better solution than the looped functions though, a function that can handle any row given to it means it'll expand or contract to your needs.